# ApexChart Pie/Donut Chart not displayed

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, apexcharts

I'm trying to get ApexCharts running on my Vue Project (I use Vue3) and I'm having issues with the piechart/donut chart. The code below **works if I change the type under the template tag to** `"bar"`

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <apexchart v-if="loaded" width="500" type="pie" :options="chartOptions" :series="series"></apexchart>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
      return {
        loaded:true,
        series: [{
            data:[23, 11, 54, 72, 12]
            }],
        chartOptions: {
            labels: ["Apple", "Mango", "Banana", "Papaya", "Orange"],
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true
            },
            responsive: [{
                breakpoint: 480,
                options: {
                    chart: {
                        width: 200
                    },
                    legend: {
                        positon:'bottom',
                        show: false
                    }
                }
            }],
        }
      }
    }
};

</script>
```

This is the result when I run in the broswer. Only the legend shows up.
[image]

I need to use Pie and Donut charts with data that I will get from the API but I'm unable to run even with static hard-coded data.

Comment: You ,misss this part chartOptions: {
            chart: {
              width: 380,
              type: 'pie',
            }, Sample here https://apexcharts.com/vue-chart-demos/pie-charts/simple-pie-chart/

Comment: @Grumpy Is that part necessary since I'm already mentioning the type in the template tag? Bar and Line charts display fine if I only change the type in the ```<apexcharts>``` to line or bar but not for pie/donut

Answer (score 6):

`series` should be a scalar array:

```js
//series: [{ data:[23, 11, 54, 72, 12] }],
series: [23, 11, 54, 72, 12]
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-apexcharts-pie?file=src/App.vue)

Comment: Thank you! I actually did try this before but I received an error that said the 'series' was missing the data property, hence why I added it. I believe the combination of this and @Grumpy 's suggested solved my issue.